# Terraform: Dynamically Create AWS EFS Mount Targets

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

OK.  I admit it.  I'm not able to figure this out.  I really really really want to like Terraform but the more I play around with it the more frustrated I'm getting and eyeing AWS CDK a little more seriously each time.

**The Situation**

1. I am creating one public and one private subnet per each availability zone in a region.  I don't necessarily know which region I'm going to deploy my resources to so I use a VPC data block for this:

```
    data "aws_availability_zones" "available" {
        state = "available"
    }
```

2. This is done in a module named, 'vpc'.  I then go off and create an EFS file system in another module named, 'efs'.  Inside of that 'efs' module, I am trying to create a set of EFS mount targets - one per each of my private subnets:

```
resource "aws_efs_mount_target" "efs_mount_targets_private" {
    for_each = toset(var.private_subnets)

    file_system_id = aws_efs_file_system.pgsql_databases.id
    security_groups = [ "${var.allow-nfs-ingress-my-vpc}" ]
    subnet_id = each.value
}
```

Some of you can guess what's coming, can't you?

3. A `terraform plan` fails:

```
Error: Invalid for_each argument
│ 
│   on modules/efs/main.tf line 55, in resource "aws_efs_mount_target" "efs_mount_targets_private":
│   XX:     for_each = toset(var.private_subnets)
│     ├────────────────
│     │ var.private_subnets is a list of string, known only after apply
```

**The Code**

Partial `main.tf` (root):

```
module "vpc" {
  count                              = terraform.workspace == "backend" ? 0 : 1
  source                             = "./modules/vpc"

  vpc_flow_logs_to_cloud_watch_group = module.cw[0].my-vpc-flow-logs-group
  vpc_flow_logs_to_cloud_watch_role  = module.iam[0].vpc_flow_logs_to_cloud_watch_role
  vpn_vgw_id = module.vpn[0].vpn-vgw-id
  nat_gw_eip = module.ec2[0].nat_gw_eip
}

module "efs" {
  count = terraform.workspace == "backend" ? 0 : 1
  source = "./modules/efs"

  vpc_id = module.vpc[0].my_vpc_id
  allow-nfs-ingress-my-vpc = module.sg-ingress[0].allow-nfs-ingress-my-vpc-id
  private_subnets = module.vpc[0].my_vpc_private_subnets
}
```

Partial `main.tf` (vpc module):

```
# Create private subnets out of odd octets
resource "aws_subnet" "my_vpc_private_subnets" {
  for_each = toset(data.aws_availability_zones.available.names)

  vpc_id = aws_vpc.my_vpc.id
  availability_zone = each.value
  cidr_block = "172.25.${2*(index(data.aws_availability_zones.available.names, each.value))+1}.0/24"

  tags = {
    auto-delete = "no"
    Name = "${each.value} subnet ${2*(index(data.aws_availability_zones.available.names, each.value))+1}"
    tier = "private"
  }
}

data "aws_subnets" "private_subnets" {
  filter {
    name = "vpc-id"
    values = [aws_vpc.my_vpc.id]
  }

  tags = {
    tier = "private"
  }

  # Without the below, this data block might evaluate to empty
  depends_on = [
    aws_subnet.my_vpc_private_subnets
  ]
}
```

Partial `outputs.tf` (vpc module):

```
output "my_vpc_private_subnets" {
  value = data.aws_subnets.private_subnets.ids
}
```

Partial `main.tf` (efs module):

```
resource "aws_efs_mount_target" "efs_mount_targets_private" {
    for_each = toset(var.private_subnets)

    file_system_id = aws_efs_file_system.pgsql_databases.id
    security_groups = [ "${var.allow-nfs-ingress-my-vpc}" ]
    subnet_id = each.value
}
```

**The Question**
Surely(?) there's a way to get around this issue WITHOUT having to do two-stage apply?  I have tried putting an `aws_subnets` data block inside of the 'ifs' module and it doesn't make a bit of difference.  Still get the same error.

If what I was trying to do wasn't possible, then how was I able to build the subnets I need off of the `aws_availability_zones` data block to begin with?

Yes, there are several other types of questions like this that I've read over but none of the answers I've found so far are really clicking for me so I apologize in advance for this indulgence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the subnets are created with `for_each` meta-argument, I think the output should be:

```
output "my_vpc_private_subnets" {
  value = values(aws_subnet.my_vpc_private_subnets)[*].id
}
```

This expression is composed from two parts:

1. The `values` built-in function [1]
2. The splat expression [2]

It will return all the values for all of the keys used in the original `for_each` in the `aws_subnet`, and the second step will filter only subnet IDs. The type of the return value will be a list of strings so that should work with the rest of the code you have for EFS. Of course, that means you can drop the `data` source for subnets from the VPC module.

---

[1] https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/values

[2] https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/splat

Comment: I had to skeptically stare at this for a while and doublecheck the splat expression docs since those are so rare in actual usage, but this does sound correct for such an esoteric situation.

Comment: I think so too, I always have to double and even triplecheck.

Comment: Thanks, Marko E.  Worked like a champ.

Comment: How does this accepted answer resolves the "known only after apply" problem? I'm still getting this error, no matter how and where "my_vpc_private_subnets" are defined.

Comment: Not sure where was that issue mentioned in the original question? Additionally, you cannot know the output until you run `terraform apply` since those values will be known when the resources are created.

Answer (score 0):

Using a `data` lookup for resources that you are also creating in the same Terraform code is an anti-pattern and it will lead to all kinds of problems, including the problem you are currently seeing.

You should completely remove the `data "aws_subnets" "private_subnets"` block, and change your `output` to:

```
output "my_vpc_private_subnets" {
  value = values(aws_subnet.my_vpc_private_subnets)[*].id
}
```

Comment: So, I gave that a shot tonight and I'm now getting the error message, "The object does not have an attribute named id".  What you have above should work though.  I've double checked and I don't have a typo.  Any other thoughts?  Is it because terraform is trying to build the output when the subnets haven't yet been created(?)

Comment: Yeah Marko's answer is correct, I was missing the `values()` conversion to convert the subnets from a map to a list.

Comment: Regardless, Mark B, I appreciate your feedback sincerely.  Thank you.